# Change the order of images in a Picture Library - Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, web-part, picture-library, sorting

I'm working on an Extranet site and have added a Picture Library Web part. There is a requirement to have the images in a certain order (not alphabetic or numerical etc).

Is it possible to change the order of the images to a manual order? If so, how?

Answer (score 2):

You could add a number column to the list, call it, say, "Sort Order", and then create a view that sorts on the values of your "Sort Order" column.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of trickery is to prepend the filenames with spaces and sort alphabetically